# How can I change the Image in UIViewController permantly

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

Apologies again if this is a noobie question, but still relatively new to swift, so please bear with me,

I am trying to change the image in a UIViewController even after the user has left the page or closed the app, the idea being that the image is pressed a password enter and the image is changed, (which I have done with the help of dzk) and the image changes as it should.

but when i leave the app page and then come back in it has reset to it's original image, so frustrating!

below is the code as it stands that will change the image after UIAlertController is validated.

Any help would be grateful.

```
class Man_VS_Cocktail : UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var Cocktail_Image: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nil

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    @IBAction func Cocktail_check_button(sender: AnyObject) {

        var password_Text: UITextField?

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "One more ticked off", message: "ask the barman to enter the password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let tickoff_action = UIAlertAction(title: "sign it off", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            action -> Void in

            if let password = password_Text?.text{
                print("password = \(password)")
                if password == "pass123" {
                self.Cocktail_Image.image = UIImage(named: "riddler_question_marks")
                }
            } else {
                print("No password entered")
            }

        }

        alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (txtpassword) -> Void in
            password_Text = txtpassword
            password_Text!.secureTextEntry = true
            password_Text!.placeholder = ""

        }

        alertController.addAction(tickoff_action)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
```

As a side note would it be possible to have master rest action that resets all images to their original state? I presume this would be an if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example on using NSDefaults.  You can change and format in a way that would fit your needs more.

```
class Man_VS_Cocktail : UIViewController{

let defaults: NSUserDefaults

@IBOutlet weak var Cocktail_Image: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Check saved password.
    let passSaved = defaults.stringForKey("password")
    if passSaved == "pass123" {
        self.Cocktail_Image.image = UIImage(named: "riddler_question_marks")
    } else {
        // Set default image.
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

@IBAction func Cocktail_check_button(sender: AnyObject) {

    var password_Text: UITextField?

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "One more ticked off", message: "ask the barman to enter the password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    let tickoff_action = UIAlertAction(title: "sign it off", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        action -> Void in

        if let password = password_Text?.text{
            print("password = \(password)")
            if password == "pass123" {
                // Save the password
                self.defaults.setObject(password_Text, forKey: "password")
                // End save password
                self.Cocktail_Image.image = UIImage(named: "riddler_question_marks")
            }
        } else {
            print("No password entered")
        }

    }

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (txtpassword) -> Void in
        password_Text = txtpassword
        password_Text!.secureTextEntry = true
        password_Text!.placeholder = ""

    }

    alertController.addAction(tickoff_action)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

You could even do a check in you your AppDelegate with the same format. You could even add some some kind of delay or clear the saved password via the AppDelegate applicationWillTerminate.